Data grid footer misbehaving when data grid is enclosed in a tab
When a mui data grid is enclosed in a mui tab the footer misbehaves when the browser window is resized.
Grid enclosed in a tab example (this URL appears to be broken by the '~' and I don't know how to prevent this)
To reproduce the behaviour when the grid is enclosed in a mui tab (the default state of the above example):

Normalise the browser window so it may be resized.
Drag the bottom of the window upwards. The footer disappears. It may be necessary to first expand the preview pane width by dragging it to the left to reproduce this behaviour.
Drag the bottom of the window down and the footer should reappear, usually.

Edit the App.tsx file and change the hard-coded bool in the if condition to false to render the grid without the tag and repeat the steps above to see the correct footer behaviour.
I assume this behaviour is caused (somehow) by the introduction of the tab component that lists the tabs. Does anyone have any suggestions an how to achieve the correct footer behaviour when the grid is enclosed in a tab?
Thanks in advance.
